# Juno IDE for Julia, how to interact?

Tags: ide, julia, juno-ide

One way to comfortably use an IDE in an interactive language is to interact via the IDE in a command line environment. I am wondering if that is a possibility in Juno. In other words, is there a command line environment as in Matlab, to call functions, give initial values, and run expressions. If so what is the way to access it?

Note: There is a console window in Juno, but I can't find a way to insert my commands inside that.

Comment: I am using Juno in windows.

Comment: Is it only possible to see the output in console, and not type inside? It might be considered a  LightTable question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** The question and this answer apply to the version of Juno that was based on LightTable. The current version is based on Atom and has an interactive console.

---

You can't enter commands into the console in Juno--that's for displaying output. Commands can be submitted from within the editor by setting your cursor in the line to submit and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The value will then be displayed in a small popup next to the line and the output will be printed to the console if you have the console visible.

Note that the inability to use the console as you desire is by design. See [here](http://junolab.org/docs/evaluation.html) for information about the console from the Juno docs.

Comment: Note that the Julia console in Juno / Atom is now interactive.