# Julia's execution using Juno gets blocked because of not being able to access the console

Tags: r, julia, rcall, juno-ide

In another question:
[Juno IDE for Julia, how to interact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901532/juno-ide-for-julia-how-to-interact/35536505#35536505)

One of the answers stated:

> You can't enter commands into the console in Juno--that's for displaying output. Commands can be submitted from within the editor by setting your cursor in the line to submit and pressing Ctrl+Enter or Shift+Enter. The value will then be displayed in a small popup next to the line and the output will be printed to the console if you have the console visible.
>
> Note that the inability to use the console as you desire is by design. See here for information about the console from the Juno docs.

I am encountering an issue that might make this design decision a bit impractical at times.

First, let me say that I am new to Julia and Juno (not to coding, just trying to learn Julia now), so there might be a way to fix this and I do not know about it.

I am using the package RCall, that allows to include R code into Julia, so I am trying to install some R packages. One of the packages is asking me a "y/n:" question and I cannot answer it because I cannot access the console, and sending code from the editor to the console using command+Enter is blocked (because the console line is executing).

To reproduce this issue (note that R 3.2.0 or above needs to be installed, and I had to restart Juno after installing RCall for it to work):

```
Pkg.add("RCall")
Pkg.build("RCall")
```

restart Juno

```
using RCall
reval("install.packages(\"rgdal\")")
```

A pop-up will appear asking to select a mirror, just choose 0 and OK. Then the package is asking me if I want to install some dependencies "y/n:" and the whole execution is blocked.

I guess that this can be fixed just by using Julia from the command line (and forgetting about Juno), but I like to use IDEs.

Do you have any ideas about how to circumvent this issue? or another IDE for Julia?

Comment: BTW, could someone with enough reputation create the tag "RCall" it does not exist and I cannot create it because I do not have 1500 points.

Comment: as a workaround, simply install all the dependencies manually: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html

Comment: also, why not just use R for package installation?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelChirico, I was thinking about that temporary solution myself, I have not tried it yet but it might work (and I will try it out). I still believe that the issue is worth reflecting on, because it might arise in other examples and I think the developers of Juno might want to know about it to take into consideration the possibility of including input in the console.

Comment: I suggest adding an issue to the [GH page](https://github.com/JuliaStats/RCall.jl/issues); honestly, though, I can't think of another situation when R requires a command prompt response (and if I'm not mistaken, there's an option you can set that will automatically install dependencies, no prompt necessary)

Comment: I don't think `RCall` is well-known enough to warrant its own tag. I'd be surprised if such a tag attracted more than a few questions over the next year. If we start seeing more `RCall` related questions on StackOverflow then of course we can re-think this.

Comment: @ColinTBowers 

*If we start seeing more RCall related questions on StackOverflow then of course we can re-think this.*

tags don't work that way, I just saw your comment after I added the `rcall` tag, the stackoverflow docs say: 

*...only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.*

and 

*...new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least **1** other question in a **6** month period.*

I have seen other `rcall` related questions.

Comment: @IsmaelVenegasCastello I did do a quick search for other `RCall` questions before posting my comment and didn't spot any... Having said that, it was a quick search - I just did a more thorough look then and found one other question (although only one). I am happy to concede that letting the automatic culling routine make the decision for us is a reasonable course to take.